# Basic File storage

Tags: file, file-storage

In order to prevent file storage problems like when two people upload a file that might have the same file name...

Is it better to get each user a separate folder to prevent issues or is better to have all files in one folder for all users but change the file-name to keep them unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve.

What kind of service do you want to provide? A general file storage service? Then use different folders, since the number of files in a directory may be limited (depending on the file system) and can have major influence on the performance.

Do you provide an upload area for a simple blog? Use a single directory and change the file names.

Sorry, an absolute answer can only be given if you provide more information.

Comment: sure.  what i want to do is allow users to upload photos.  So i want to prevent any issues with rednering the code, so lets say you uploaed ckruse.png and then two weeks later by chance i uploaded and deleted something called ckruse.png i want it to be unique...

Comment: I would go for a unique directory per user as it leaves the filenames of the users intact (nicer URIs) and it also solves the problems of to many files in a directory